# How to replace froogaloop2.min.js for product videos?

Tags: product-video

The videoes on my products have stopped working. And I have found that it's froogaloop2.min.js being the problem. The trouble is, this is an external file and I have seen that it has been retired [here](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/blob/master/docs/migrate-from-froogaloop.md) and how to update it...

But the problem is, I don't know where I update this in magento. Would anyone be able to provide some guidance/a tutorial on how to do this? I just can't find any file that even calls the froogaloop file.

I am on Magento 2.2.0

Comment: the videos you are using as product videos are uploaded on vimeo ?

Comment: Yes they are. A play icon appears over the image/thumbnail, when play is hit, it doesn't load. And it seems froogaloop is the problem.

Comment: so that this js file is coming along with video code , because as you embed the video it calls the related iframe and show the video. did you check youtube ? to show videos

Comment: I haven't checked youtube because I am wanting to use Vimeo for it. I can check youtube in a bit, just annoying having to setup API etc

Comment: Youtube works fine. I checked the github for magento, it seems others are having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past that problem by simply replacing the reference to froogaloop2.min.js for this one...
https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js

Comment: how exactly do you replace the ref?